# What's the rest mass tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

What's [rest-mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rest-mass) for? It's probably *too* specific. Why not burinate it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [rest-mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rest-mass) should be a synonym to (or merged with) [mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass).

Comment: A merge makes sense here. +/- synonym doesn't matter much in this case imo, but a synonym prevents accidental recreation so that helps.